# Find similar words between 2 arrays levenshtein

Tags: php, arrays, levenshtein-distance

I'm trying to find 2 similar words on a list, If you have 2 arrays of words like this:

```
$words = array("peace", "loving", "air", "earth");

$category = array("lover", "something", "example", "peace"); // (actually I have more than 1000 categories)
```

the most similar (or exact) word would be "`peace`", so it can print the word of the array `$category` and exclude the rest of them.

Example 1:

[image]

But when I write more text (quotes) sometimes it doesn't match any category and just show blank, even if there's some category with similar text and show this:

Example 2:

[image]

This is my code that runs into a "`for`" cicle to receive each quote and separate each of them with `preg_split()`:

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($text);$i++) { ?>
<!-- Quote -->
<td><textarea name="txtquote[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="txtquote[<?php echo $i; ?>]" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo trim($text[$i]); ?></textarea></td>

<!-- Category -->
<?php
$rows = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetCategory);
if($rows > 0) { mysql_data_seek($RecordsetCategory, 0);
while ($row_RecordsetCategory = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetCategory)) { 

$input = $row_RecordsetCategory['category'];
$words  = str_word_count($text[$i],1);
$shortest = -1;

foreach ($words as $word) {
 $lev = levenshtein($input, $word);
   if ($lev == 0) {
     $closest = $word;
     $shortest = 0;
     break;
   }
   if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
     $closest  = $word;
     $shortest = $lev;
     }
   }

  if ($shortest == 0) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetCategory['id']?>"><?php echo $closest;?></option>
    <?php } } } 

} // end 
?>
```

What can I do to avoid that?, find the similar word of the category when I write more text and it doesn't get a white combobox.

Comment: Please debug, and let us know where exactly you are failing.